# Authenticate storage account with service principal

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

In java, I want to authenticate using a service principal (preference using client certificate) to write/read files from blobstorage.

I started out using StorageAccount and access keys but I need to have more fine grained permission controll (limiting to only reading or writing for example).

I can't find any example in the azure docs on how to do this, neither any entry points in the code.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, Azure does not provide a [build-in role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-blob-data-contributor) which just has read/write permissions to Blob storage resources. So we need to [create a custom role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles-powershell) according to your need. Then you can assign the role to the service principal. Regarding 
Gow to create a custom role, please refer to the steps as below

1. Define a role json

   ```
   {
     "Name": "Azure blob Writer",
     "Id": null,
     "IsCustom": true,
     "Description": "Read and write blob",
     "Actions": [
       "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/read", 
       "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/write", 
       "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/generateUserDelegationKey/action"
     ],
     "DataActions": [
       "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/read", 
        "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/write"
     ],
     "NotActions": [],
     "AssignableScopes": [
       "/subscriptions/<subscription id>"
     ]

   }
   ```

   2. Create a custom role with PowerShell

      New-AzureRmRoleDefinition -InputFile "the path of your JSON file"

Besides, if you use access keys, you can generate a SAS toekn with account key. [SAS toekn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json) can be configured permisions according to your need. Regarding how to create SAS token, please refer to the following code.

```
SharedKeyCredentials credential = new SharedKeyCredentials(accountName, accountKey);

        // This is the name of the container and blob that we're creating a SAS to.
        String containerName = "mycontainer"; // Container names require lowercase.
        String blobName = "HelloWorld.txt"; // Blob names can be mixed case.
        String snapshotId = "2018-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z"; // SAS can be restricted to a specific snapshot

        /*
        Set the desired SAS signature values and sign them with the shared key credentials to get the SAS query
        parameters.
         */
        ServiceSASSignatureValues values = new ServiceSASSignatureValues()
                .withProtocol(SASProtocol.HTTPS_ONLY) // Users MUST use HTTPS (not HTTP).
                .withExpiryTime(OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(2)) // 2 days before expiration.
                .withContainerName(containerName)
                .withBlobName(blobName)
                .withSnapshotId(snapshotId);

        /*
        To produce a container SAS (as opposed to a blob SAS), assign to Permissions using ContainerSASPermissions, and
        make sure the blobName and snapshotId fields are null (the default).
         */
        BlobSASPermission permission = new BlobSASPermission()
                .withRead(true)
                .withAdd(true)
                .withWrite(true);
        values.withPermissions(permission.toString());

        SASQueryParameters params = values.generateSASQueryParameters(credential);
```

For more deatis, you can refer to the [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/blob/89540f018f1160ce55619c6fe7b5f5ff57d0ce10/src/test/java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/Samples.java#L513).